# Django ArrayField - Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, arrays, django, list, django-serializer

I want to store an array in my database. For that I use ArrayType of this type in my model: `[[[0.29, 10.27]]]`. I would like to use a serializer to create my GET, POST and PUT requests.
Here is my model:

**models.py**

```
class Area(models.Model):
    osm = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            ArrayField(
                models.FloatField(),
                size=2,
            ),
        ),
    )
```

Here is my serializer :

**serializer.py**

```
class AreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Area
        fields = ['osm', ]
```

And here is my view :

**views.py**

```
class ShopAreaList(ShopCustomListView):
    """Get or create areas for a shop"""
    queryset = Shop.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'path'

    def get(self, request, path):
        """Depends on mustBeLogged to get areas of a shop"""
        shop = self.get_object()
        areas = Area.objects.filter(shop=shop)
        serializer = AreaSerializer(areas, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, path):
        """For admin or shop owner to create areas"""
        shop = self.get_object()
        serializer = AreaSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(shop=shop)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Here is the data I get:

```
{
    "osm": [[[0.29, 10.27]]]
}
```

When I try to run my POST method I get this error:

```
Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I don't know what can I do to fix this error.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: what database backend are you using?

Comment: I'm not in production in this case so I'm using a sqlite3 database, but in production I would like to use a postgresql database

Comment: more than likely then the error is caused from the sqlite3 backend not supporting ArrayField, to fix this you would need to move to a Postgresql database and backend

Comment: It actually works with a postgresql database, thank you